# How to rewrite rand.Seed(1) when migrate from go 1.13 to 1.20.1?

Tags: go

File `bench.go`

```golang
package bench

import "os"

func FileLen(f string, bufsize int) (int, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(f)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    count := 0
    buf := make([]byte, bufsize)
    for {
        num, err := file.Read(buf)
        count += num
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    return count, nil
}
```

File `bench_test.go`

```golang
package bench

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    makeData()
    exitVal := m.Run()
    os.Remove("testdata/data.txt")
    os.Exit(exitVal)
}

// makeData makes our data file for us. Rather than checking in a large file, we recreate it for the test.
// By setting the random seed to the same value every time, we ensure that we generate the same file every time.
// This random seed generates a file that's 65,204 bytes long.
func makeData() {
    file, err := os.Create("testdata/data.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    rand.Seed(1)
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        data := makeWord(rand.Intn(10) + 1)
        file.Write(data)
    }
}

func makeWord(l int) []byte {
    out := make([]byte, l+1)
    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        out[i] = 'a' + byte(rand.Intn(26))
    }
    out[l] = '\n'
    return out
}

func TestFileLen(t *testing.T) {
    result, err := FileLen("testdata/data.txt", 1)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if result != 65204 {
        t.Error("Expected 65204, got", result)
    }
}

var blackhole int

func BenchmarkFileLen1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        result, err := FileLen("testdata/data.txt", 1)
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
        blackhole = result
    }
}

func BenchmarkFileLen(b *testing.B) {
    for _, v := range []int{1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000} {
        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("FileLen-%d", v), func(b *testing.B) {
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                result, err := FileLen("testdata/data.txt", v)
                if err != nil {
                    b.Fatal(err)
                }
                blackhole = result
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

https://github.com/learning-go-book-2evy/test_examples/blob/master/bench/bench_test.go#L27

I tried change to `rand.NewSource(1)` but test fail. How to rewrite `rand.Seed(1)` when migrate from go 1.13 to 1.20.1?

Comment: Deprecation produces a warning, not an error. Your code will compile and run OK.  You can use deprecated methods, just realise that one day they might be removed from a future version.

Answer (score 3):

As of Go 1.20.1 there is an error in the documentation for rand.Rand. It reads

> Programs that need a specific result sequence should use NewRand(NewSource(seed)).

The constructor for the PRNG is called `New`, not `NewRand`.

To replace uses of the global seed, pass the return value of rand.NewSource to rand.New to obtain a PRNG. This PRNG then has the same API as the package level functions:

```golang
package main

import "math/rand"

func main() {
    rng := rand.New(rand.NewSource(1))
    n := rng.Intn(10) + 1 // instead of rand.Intn
    _ = n
}
```

---

Changing the original to the following will pass the benchmark tests:

```golang
func makeData() {
    file, err := os.Create("testdata/data.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(1))
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        data := makeWord(r.Intn(10)+1, r)
        file.Write(data)
    }
}

func makeWord(l int, r *rand.Rand) []byte {
    out := make([]byte, l+1)
    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        out[i] = 'a' + byte(r.Intn(26))
    }
    out[l] = '\n'
    return out
}
```